# unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (251, 246). Other element would receive the click

Tags: python

URL : http://www.iros.go.kr/PMainJ.jsp

I want to click the xpath as follows.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a').click()
```

But got this error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (251, 246). Other element would receive the click: ...
>     (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)

How can I fix this error? Thanks